# Page not found (404) - No Post matches the given query

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm working on a Django blog, and having implemented slug for post titles I've stumbled upon an issue.
The error is

> Page not found (404)
>   Request Method: GET
>   Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/post/new/
>   Raised by:  blog.views.post_detail
>   No Post matches the given query.

This is my **urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list),
    url(r'^register', views.register),
    url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/', views.register_confirm),
    url(r'^email_check', views.email_check),
    url(r'^password_check', views.password_check),
    url(r'^login', views.login),
    url(r'^edit/$', views.update_profile),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', views.post_detail),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name='post_edit'),
    url(r'^drafts/$', views.post_draft_list, name='post_draft_list'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/publish/$', views.post_publish, name='post_publish'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/remove/$', views.post_remove, name='post_remove'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/comment/$', views.add_comment_to_post, name='add_comment_to_post'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/approve/$', views.comment_approve, name='comment_approve'),
    url(r'^comment/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/remove/$', views.comment_remove, name='comment_remove'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

The **view.py** file

```
@login_required
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('blog.views.post_detail', slug=post.slug)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_new.html', {'form': form})
```

It says that the error is raised by "post_detail", so here it is

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is happening because `new` matches the regex `[-_\w]+`.

You have to re-order the url entries in your url patterns

Change this:

```
url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', views.post_detail),
url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
```

With this:

```
url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', views.post_detail),
```

**Explanation**:

The `post_detail` url entry in your code is evaluated before `post_new` url. This gives `post_detail` more priority over `post_new`.

Since `post_detail` url is `/post/` + *anything that matches* `[-_\w]+` and `new` matches the regex, Django thinks that you are passing `new` as the `slug` for `post_detail` view and passes it as a keyword argument to the view. Since there is no post with `new` as slug, the view returns `404 Not found`.

When `post_new` is above `post_detail`, `/post/new/` points to `post_new` view and `/post/` + anything with regex match points to `post_detal`.

Comment: It works (thank you!), but I'm not sure if I understood the reason why.